# How can I parallelize a for loop in spark with scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For example, we have a parquet file with 2000 stock symbols' closing price in the past 3 years, and we want to calculate the 5-day moving average for each symbol.

So I create a spark SQLContext and then

```
val marketData = sqlcontext.sql("select DATE, SYMBOL, PRICE from stockdata order by DATE").cache()
```

To get the symbol list,

```
val symbols = marketData.select("SYMBOL").distinct().collect()
```

and here is the for loop:

```
for (symbol <- symbols) {
  marketData.filter(symbol).rdd.sliding(5).map(...calculating the avg...).save()
}
```

Obviously, doing the for loop on spark is slow, and `save()` for each small result also slows down the process (I have tried define a `var result` outside the for loop and union all the output to make the IO operation together, but I got a stackoverflow exception), so how can I parallelize the for loop and optimize the IO operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program you write runs in a driver ("master") spark node. Expressions in this program can only be parallelized if you are operating on parallel structures (RDDs).

Try this:

```
marketdata.rdd.map(symbolize).reduceByKey{ case (symbol, days) => days.sliding(5).map(makeAvg)  }.foreach{ case (symbol,averages) => averages.save() }
```

where `symbolize` takes a Row of symbol x day and returns a tuple (symbol, day).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the `marketdata` contains all the market data (2000 symbol × 900 day = 1800000 rows) and if we `sliding(5)` on this rdd without `filter(symbol)` seems will got a wrong result about moving average? Did I make myself clear?

Comment: Thanks for you patience. And as far as I know, if we have a `symbolize` like `{ row => (row.getAs[String]("SYMBOL"), row) }` and `reduceByKey` on the rdd that `map(symbolize)` returns we will have to `reduceByKey{ case (row_x, row_y) => ...}` instead of `reduceByKey{ case (symbol, days) => ...}`, finally, I `groupByKey()` on the rdd that `map(symbolize)` returns and `mapValues(x => x.sliding(5).map(makeAvg)).save()` and that works. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of the answer I don't agree with Carlos. The program does not run in the driver ("master").

The loop does run sequentially, but for each symbol the execution of:

```
marketData.filter(symbol).rdd.sliding(5).map(...calculating the avg...).save()
```

is done in parallel since `markedData` is a Spark DataFrame and it is distributed.